# How to import many dataframes from R into a one Excel file in a simple way?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, datatables

I have this dataset (let's imagine it with 900 variables )

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1), y = c(2,2,2,2,3,3,2) )

l1 = lapply(df,table)

l2 = lapply(l1,as.data.frame)
```

I created a list of dataframes that I wish to be extracted to a one file excel in a simple way using `lapply` or something like this. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write_xlsx()` from `writexl` saves each list item in one sheet of an Excel file:

```r
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(l2, 'file.xlsx')
```

Comment: is there a way to have all the dataframes in one sheet instead of multiple ones ?

Comment: If they all have the same columns, you can do `write_xlsx(do.call(rbind, l2), 'file.xlsx')`.